# Error C2040: 'void *()' differs in levels of indirection from 'int ()'

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    myfunction();
}

void* myfunction() {
    char *p;
    *p = 0;
    return (void*) &p;
}
```

When the program run at Visual Studio, it could not compile and the error message goes like below:

```
"Error 2 error C2040: 'myfunction' : 
'void *()' differs in levels of indirection from 'int ()' "
```

Could someone explain?

Comment: Although this is not the error you see, do you know that your program is going to give you a segmentation fault since you're dereferencing an uninitialized memory location ? The variable `char* p` is uninitialized and you're trying to assign a value 0 to the address stored in `p`.

Comment: Do you mean that it should be, say p=0, rather than *p=0 ? Because every pointer must be initialized before using it?

Comment: No `*p = 0` is a valid statement, but what it does is assigns the memory location which `p` points to with `0`. Since the pointer `p` is uninitialized, the memory it points to will be some garbage address. So you're trying to write into some garbage address which will cause the `segmentation fault`.

Comment: Initialization? such as p = &something ? Thus p is then set to some address, rather than garbage collection? Thx!

Comment: Yes exactly `p = &someething` or `p = malloc(sizeof(char))`

Answer (score 4):

You should add the declaration of `myfunction()` before useing it in `main()` function:

```
void* myfunction(void);

int main(void)
{
    myfunction();
    return 0;
}

void* myfunction(void) {
    char *p;
    *p = 0;
    return (void*) &p;
}
```

try it.

Answer (score 2):

Your program has two problems. The first problem is the one mentioned in [Nan Xiao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15192925/82320), whereby the compiler is assuming the signature of `myfunction` is `int myfunction()` upon seeing your call in `main`.

The second problem is you have incorrect levels of indirection inside `myfunction` itself:

```
void* myfunction(void) {
    char *p; // Create a pointer to a character
    *p = 0;  // Set some random location to zero
    return (void*) &p; // Take the address of the pointer to a character,
                       // and turn it into a pointer to anything
}
```

That is, your cast is taking `char **` and making a `void *` with it, which is probably not what you wanted.

If you want to return the character pointer cast to a void pointer, just return the character pointer itself, without the cast.

Comment: By the way, why did you say it "randomly set location"? Could you please explain a little more on it? And in what situation not random? Thx

Comment: @user: Because you never set what "p" points to, and then attempt to write to whatever it points to.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I misread your code. Answer has been updated.

As @Nan Xiao notes, you should declare myfunction before calling it. I can only assume that your compiler is wrongly assuming it exists and returns an int, which causes the complaint later.

I believe it is complaining that the function was initially "defined" as returning an int, but now it finds one which returns a void*. int has 0 levels of indirection (it's not a pointer), whereas void* has one (it could point to an int, for example). Continuing, void** has two levels of indirection (points to something which could point to an int).

In C, while you can safely convert (say) double to int, you cannot convert int* to int without explaining how to do it (should it dereference or use the address?).

Comment: Another stupid question: what do you mean by "dereference" and use the address? My guess was *p and &p. isn't it?

Comment: Close. dereferencing is indeed *p, but to just use the address (my terminology; probably not official!) is to say (int) p, which would give you the actual memory address which it is pointing to as an integer. Because the compiler doesn't know which you want to do it throws an error. You have to tell it explicitly.